Paint for GT Dyno
I need to know what paint and what years my gt dyno is. The serial number of the gt is SY7D000287. I have search on Google and local paint shops. And no one can help me

What do you want us to do with the serial number? What will knowing the year do for you? Have you contacted GT with any of these questions?

Can you show us a photo of your bike as it is now?  What colour do you like the most and what's stopping you painting it that colour ?

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Serial numbers are not like VINs; they are unique to each manufacturer, not standard, and mostly not described. Your best bet is to try contacting the manufacturer.  Of course there are no standard paints either.

Unfortunately bike manufacturing doesn't work lik cars so the paint code isn't recorded in the manufacturer logs or anywhere. Take the frame to a car paint shop that has a RAL or Pantone colour swatch set and find the closest one. Nobody can tell the difference.

Sometimes it's not possible to identify the year or model.
Serial numbers often don't help. For most bike makers there is no published information on decoding a serial number.
For GT there have been enthusiast efforts to decipher the various codes used as serial numbers over the years. They are not official (they are not published by the maker and therefore not authoritative) and there are gaps in the data. I would trust matching a bike to a picture of a bike with a known maker/model/year over these efforts.
There has been work done to try to interpret serial numbers for GT bicycles.
Here is one attempt
Here is another attempt
I didn't find a Dyno serial number lookup but I did find an attempt to create a reference guide for Dyno's.

With BMX bikes my best resource is BMXmuseum.com.
In your case you have identified the bicycle maker as a GT Dyno.
GT is one maker of bicycles. Here is a link to GT bikes listed on BMXmuseum .
Dyno is a different maker of bicycles. Here is a link to Dyno bikes listed on BMXmuseum.
They were often very similar but when searching it's one or the other.

You'll want to narrow your search to the specific maker, either GT or Dyno. If GT is stamped in the metal somewhere on the frame or there is an original GT sticker (stickers can be purchased and are not always reliable as an indicator). Same thing for Dyno.
Then search the pictures for the specific maker for a frame that matches yours.
Hopefully, there will be something about your bike that will let you associate it with the pictures for a specific year or range of years the bike was made. The best way to match is by frame and by some unique feature of the frame that allows you to match it with the picture of a known bike. Matching removable parts can be misleading.

Happy hunting
